# PhpStorm and Remote XDebug not working

Tags: php, nginx, phpstorm, xdebug

I've followed multiple tutorials to set up XDebug with PhpStorm but it seems like
I'm not lucky with it at all. No matter what I try, it's always stuck with
**Waiting for incoming connection with ide key 'PHPSTORM'**
But when I reload the page with CTRL + R I can see for a *split second* **connected**.
However, then it switches back to "Waiting.."
I've tried the XDebug Chrome Plugin and the PHPStorm XDebug Generator Bookmarks
aswell as enabling *"Start listening for PHP Debug Connections"* in PHPStorm.
I'm Using NginX with php5-fpm and tried *tcpdump 9089*.
As said, for a split second it dumps it. But then it's lost again..

Can someone please help me?

My php.ini config :

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php5/20121212/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=9089
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profilter_output_dir="/tmp/xdebug.log"
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
```

My PHPStorm Settings :

[image: PHP Interpreter Settings]

[[image: PHP Server Settings[2]]

[image: PHP Debug Settings]

[image: Debug Configuration]

**EDIT** : I have NO IDEA why, but removing `xdebug.remote_connect_back=1`
and replacing it with `xdebug.remote_host=my.ip.add.ess` made it work?!
As I've read the docs I had the understanding that the first setting is for implicit requests
while the later one is for an explicit ip request..

Comment: My xdebug behaves similarly if I try to debug a PHP __script__ rather than a full project (classes, functions etc), perhaps bare that in mind as to where you put your breakpoints. Secondly, have you tried using `xdebug.remote_host = ...` instead of `remote_connect_back`?

Comment: As I'm using a laravel project I've set a breakpoint where I'm fetching data from the database. And no, I didn't try remote_host as I've read that `xdebug.remote_connect_back=1` is the 'same', just for all incoming connections instead of a specific IP

Comment: Please collect and provide xdebug logs for such unsuccessful debug session: http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_log

Comment: *"I have NO IDEA why, but removing..."* Possibly wrong IP was automatically detected (you have to look into xdebg log for that) or your firewall was blocking connections on that IP (e.g. because it belongs to different subnetwork/firewall profile)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the following setting a try, sounds funny but just copy past the entire block instead of typing them in (believe you me that helped a couple of colleague of mine)

```
xdebug.remote_host=10.0.2.2
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.show_exception_trace=0
xdebug.show_local_vars=0
xdebug.var_display_max_data=10000
xdebug.var_display_max_depth=20
xdebug.max_nesting_level=200
```

p.s.

I assume you have the extinction file is exists in your guest machine (Virtual Machine) since you said it will stops at the breakpoint for split of sound

Also i assume your browser is sending the correct "PHPSTORM"